# What does it mean?

Tags: web, web-applications, sql-injection

> ```
> string query = "SELECT * 
>                 FROM users 
>                 WHERE username = "'" + username + "' 
>                       AND password = '" + password + "'";
> ```
>
> Since this query is constructed by concatenating an input string directly from the user, the query behaves correctly only if password does not contain a single-quote character. If the user enters
>
> ```
> __"
> joe
> "
> as the username and
> "
> example' OR 
>  'a'='a
> as the password, the resulting query 
> becomes__
> ```

I want to know what the single quote character means

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

Comment: Please next time use more orthodox formatting for your question.

Comment: No my question is different

Comment: `"` - double quote character, `'` - single quote character

Comment: @ PM 77-1   i think you are so tallented thats y you giving this nonsense answer..